# Can't get rid of space behind images in divs as table-cells //inline-blocks

Tags: html, css

(I have everything set to 0)(Note that the images height is unknown and they are centered)

This is the code:

```
<div id="ctl06_ImagesPanel">
    <div style=" padding: 0px; margin: 0px; width:300px; display:table-cell; vertical-align: middle; background:Blue;">
        <div style=" display:inline-block; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">
            <img src="Media/2/M213907891711W.jpg" id="ctl06_ctl00_MediaImage" style="margin:0px;" alt="Option 1" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style=" padding: 0px; margin: 0px; width:300px; display:table-cell; vertical-align: middle; background:Blue;">
        <div style=" display:inline-block; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">
            <img src="Media/2/M213907891712W.jpg" id="ctl06_ctl01_MediaImage" style="margin:0px;" alt="Option 2" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add `vertical-align:top` to the `img` elements:

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/MUgZb/)

```
#ctl06_ImagesPanel img {
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

The default value of the `vertical-align` property is `baseline`, that's why you were getting a `~2px` space at the bottom of the `img` elements.

Comment: This was a fast one. I thought i already tried that in the css file but i messed up something.

Comment: @SaintJob2.0 Is that what you were looking for, or were you referring to another space?

Comment: Yes it was that. I just couldn't accept the answer so fast. Thanks.

Comment: Well... apparently this works for firefox, but doesn't for IE. Any idea?

Comment: @SaintJob2.0 That's odd, I hadn't tested it in IE. It seems like `vertical-align:middle` works in Chrome/FF/IE. I have no idea why `top` didn't work in IE. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/gmy6k/) it works in IE10, not sure about other versions.

Comment: I'm using IE11 and the example doesn't work either. Chrome and FF are fine. Checking more things.

Comment: Ok, vertical-align:middle; works for: IE,FF,CH,Safari. Maybe middle was needed because the table-cell had vertical-align middle?